# Execute javascript script after Require.js finished setting up config

Tags: jquery, cordova, requirejs

I'm creating a Phonegap app. I'm using Require.js and am implementing Push Notification. In my index.html file I have:

```
<script data-main="js/app" src="js/require.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/app/index.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    app.initialize();
</script>
```

The app.js defines the base url for Require.js modules and initiates the router. Index.html defines the "deviceready" listener. The problem is that within index.js, I need to have accress to Require.js modules, such as Jquery. But for example, in index.js, if I do:

```
initialize: function() {

    require(["jquery"], function () {

    });
},
```

I get the error:

```
Uncaught Error: Script error for: jquery
http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#scripterror at file:///android_asset/www/js/require.js:8
Uncaught Error: Load timeout for modules: backbone
http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#timeout at file:///android_asset/www/js/require.js:8
```

I think this is because index.js is called whilst app.js is still setting up paths etc. I need index.js to execute after app.js is finished. I CANNOT use:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
        app.initialize();
    });
```

because Jquery is loaded as a module so will throw an error. I also cannot load index.js as a module because of a problem I wrote about in another SO question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21289443/require-js-with-phonegap-and-push-notification-for-ios).

Any ideas what I can do?

Answer (score 2):

If you load your main file with a separate `<script>` tag rather than with `data-main`, then your configuration for RequireJS will run right away:

```
<script src="js/require.js"></script>
<script src="js/app.js"></script>
```

This may be problematic depending on what `js/app.js` contains. If it causes problems, then you can split this file into a) a file that contains only RequireJS's configuration (let's call it `js/requirejs-config.js`), b) the app proper (which would still be called `js/app.js`). So something like:

```
<script src="js/require.js"></script>
<script src="js/require-config.js"></script>
<script>
    require(["js/app"]);
</script>
```

Or you could possibly add a top-level [`deps`](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#config-deps) field to your configuration like this `deps: ["js/app"]` so as to avoid needing the third `<script>` tag.

Comment: This actually works when i run in the browser. But, somehow, there's another error (Script error for: app) when i run in a phonegap app...

Comment: I am unfamiliar with Phonegap. See this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16859651/is-it-wise-to-use-an-amd-loader-like-requirejs-with-a-phonegap-cordova-applicati) regarding the problems people generally face using Phonegap and RequireJS together.

Answer (score -1):

I ran into the same issue with my cordova app on ios.  The dynamic loading failed with the same error, though I have the same code running well on the browser.

My workaround is to first statically load the module, via defining shim.deps of the 'app' in data-main, so the module gets loaded initially via require.  Subsequently it's then available when module is needed - require(["jquery"]) will then be ok.

Definitely want to get to the root of the problem though, but for now I can proceed.